# Gson not working with parent class in Java

Tags: java, json, inheritance, gson

I have three classes UserMini, User and Reply. User extends UserMini and reply has one UserMini Object in it along with content and other information.

UserMini (this.user) object is created in Reply class as follows:

```
private void getUserObject () {
   this.user = (UserMini)new User(email, fname,  lname, userid...);
}
```

UserMini class stores only fname and lname of user.

I want to do the following: return JSON value of Reply class with all the information in it. I do that with following code in reply class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
}
```

This does fine job, JSON mapping of everything stored in Reply object. But for Reply's UserMini object outputs following value:

```
user:
    accessToken: "0",
    email: "email@gmail.com",
    firstName: "FirstName",
    lastName: "LastName",
    picturePath: "Pic_path",
    refreshToken: "0",
    userId: "2"
```

As you see I store parent object in the Reply class and Gson outputs child's properties despite that.

I want to avoid Gson Adapters, is there any other way make Gson output following value for MiniUser Object:

```
user:
    firstName: "FirstName",
    lastName: "LastName"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gson` is using `getClass(`) method to determine type of object. Reflection is run-time. `getClass()` returns actual type run-time of object and not initially declared static type of variable. Cast not changes variable type, just tells compiler to treat variable as it is of other type. After compilation casts is lost, compiled program has no information about casts made in code.

Comment: Thanks for your exhausting answer, Giorgi. I got it. Although you must have said that I needed to add "transitive" keyword to the property.